# Clarification: Difference between Talend DI & Talend Enterprise version

Tags: talend

I would like to understand difference between Talend DI and Talend enterprise version.
Please share your knowledge in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

Talend is constantly changing the naming of his products, so it is quite difficult to know what is behind the name of a version.

Here is a page on talend site :
https://www.talend.com/products/

Talend Data Integration is the 'core' product, with which you can work with talend components to integrate data. It is the equivalent of "Talend Open Studio for Data Integration" in the licensed ecosystem.

Talend Enterprise no longer appears : it is now rebranded as Talend Data Fabric , which is an aggregation of different Talend Apps.

You have to constantly watch for new products rebranding, so bookmark the link given above, as it is my main source of information on this subject.

Comment: Thank you for your response and it is very useful for my reference

Answer (score 0):

With the enterprise addition you get additional components that aid mult-user development such as bitbucket(git), TAC - Talend Admin Console that assists scheduling of job amongst others including Big Data components etc. However having said that, you do get a lot in the free version which is a standalone dev tool and mostly there are workarounds for the above but can take significantly longer.